# Django static site search with no database

Tags: django, search, static

I have a private website that I host, created in Django, with only static content. I would like to make a search for the site, but the site is not connected to a database, which takes away my ability to use most pre-made back/front end search utilities. Does anyone have any idea's on how to accomplish this search, or any applications that would work in this situation.

Thanks for whatever help you may be able to provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you said your site is not connected to the database, you can add one. For private sites **SQLite** should do the trick and it is able to support ~100.000 db hits per day (according to their site: http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html).

If you do not have a lot of traffic and do not want to use some RDBMS solutions that require some separate daemon running, SQLite is one of the best approaches - it is supported easily in Python/Django without any effort and does not need any server, just a path to a file it will use as database.

Comment: I ended up going with a mySQL database, a bit faster. But thank you for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Xapian](http://xapian.org/) or [Whoosh](http://packages.python.org/Whoosh/index.html). Neither requires an independent database. (Xapian is slightly more difficult to setup but is *much* faster than Whoosh)

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to check those out